# Please unlock and reopen “What are extern variables in C?”

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, specific-question, locked-questions

The question [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c) was closed as “not a real question” and immediately locked. Yet it is squarely on-topic (it's about programming, not about programmer cartoons). It has no history of debate (it didn't go through any close-reopen cycle). It has a great answer which deserves being preserved (which locking achieves) *and curated* (which locking prevents).

The only close reason I can see that could apply to this question is *too broad*. But unlike other close reasons, the proof of *too broad* is in the answering. Jonathan Leffler has managed to write a great answer, and that proves that the question was answerable.

The question should be refocused a little on the points that the answer addresses, to wit, the use of `extern` to share variables across source files. This is the kind of improvements that locking prevents.

This question belongs open, not preserved as a historical work of bad art. Please unlock it and reopen it.

Comment: This is a great example of what is wrong with some people being able to close questions without supporting close votes from others.

Comment: IMO, should remain closed but for a different, more up to date reason. I agree the answer is great but the question itself is poor doesnt show any research, like you said too-broad. It should be aimed at a specific 'thing' the OP doesnt understand about the extern variable. A question like: *what is a variable?* would get closed straight away too

Comment: @not-rightfold Please do not hijack this meta question into an anti-moderator crusade. I am not fully satisfied with moderation on SO either, but that is not my point here. I am only concerned with the fate of this particular question, perhaps also of others like it, but definitely not about closing in general. Also, speaking as a moderator: of course moderators should be able to close questions, it's part of the job.

Comment: @mehow Lack of research is a reason to downvote, not a reason to vote to close. For an old question with a great answer like this, the reason for asking the question is no longer relevant anyway: the question should be adjusted for the answer.

Comment: @Gilles Lack of research is by now an explicit reason to vote to close. I'm not sure if I would have gone with the lock, but I would surely have voted to close. But as "too broad" most likely.

Comment: @Gilles a question should never be adjusted to match the answer? what

Comment: I won't speak for the closure of the question, but that question should not be locked. Sure it may be a little broad, but locking it puts it in the same category as all the wedding cake questions. What worries me is that if a question like *this* can get locked, then it opens the door to locking *many* similar massively useful questions.

Comment: @Bart No, lack of research is not a reason to vote to close. Even on SO. If you're refering to “demonstrate a minimal understanding”, that's different: it doesn't mention research. It asks for an attempt to solve the problem, but not for research. Whereas “does not show any research effort” is an official reason to downvote.

Comment: I would happen to disagree there @Gilles. But let me not hijack this any further and keep it focused on this question. It might be a discussion for another day. I agree however that this should not be locked. I don't know why that was done however.

Comment: Looking at the history, I'm not sure why I locked it at all. I think I've only locked maybe three questions for historical before, and I know two were in response to meta posts. I likely locked it to prevent it from being deleted, either way. I'll leave it locked for now so it doesn't get delete votes until we're done talking about it.

Comment: The fact that Jonathan Leffler's answer to the question is about as long as a book seems like a good indication that the question was broad enough that a book could be written on the subject. It's a good answer and thus probably deserves a historical lock, but if the proof is in the answering for Too Broad, this giant answer and the 12 other not-as-good answers prove it just fine for me.

Comment: @Wooble No, having an excellent answer doesn't necessarily mean that the question is too broad. The test is whether the answer covers the subject adequately, and it does. The *too broad* close reason exists for two purposes: to avoid requiring too much work from answerers (which is moot if somebody puts in that work), and to avoid questions where the answers are too partial and thus unhelpful (which isn't a problem here since Jonathan managed to cover the subject well).

Comment: I've seen people take the time to answer all kinds of bad questions; I don't buy that them making the admirable effort means the question was a good one.

Comment: @Wooble You're applying bad criteria — trying to judge the asker rather than the thread. (Keep in mind that when you act on a question, it has consequences for the answers as well: you can't completely judge a question in isolation.) What makes the internet better? To close the question, or to leave it open? The answer is very useful to have around, and it's in the right place. Therefore the question should stay.

Comment: The whole point of having a historical lock is to allow good answers to bad questions stay around and be good for the internet.